# Can't select my field and also I can't write there with codeception

Tags: php, testing, composer-php, automated-tests, codeception

I'm trying to write a small test where I login to my chosen page. I want to write my email address to login field and press the button to login. However, I receive an error that I miss argument in my fillField function.

> [ArgumentCountError] Too few arguments to function AcceptanceTester::fillField(), 1 passed in C:\Users\Henrikas\tests\acceptance\LoginCest.php on line 11 and exactly 2 expected

Here's my code: public function successTest(AcceptanceTester $I)

```
 {

        $I->wantTo("Created test case for login");
        $I->amOnPage('page');
        $I->fillField(['input' => '.form-control', "myEmailAddress"]);
        $I->click("//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block btn-rounded text-uppercase']");
}
}
```

And error picture:
[image]

HTML code from my webiste:
[image]

Comment: My mistake in code. After .form-control added ]. However, right now I receive an error :[PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] Array to string conversion

Comment: Have you even read that error message? Why don't you supply a second argument to `fillField`?

Comment: Yea I did, not recognize that ']' was in a wrong place.

Comment: `$I->fillField(['input' => '.form-control'], "myEmailAddress");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fillField` method of codeception takes two parameters of type string
1. The selector
2. The value

You have provided an array in both cases. 
You might want to write the test case using xpath like this

```
public function successTest(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->wantTo("Created test case for login");
    $I->amOnPage('page');
    $I->fillField("//input[@type='text']", "myEmailAddress");
    $I->click("//button");
}
```

Depending on how your button element is.