# Codeception error Form field by Label or CSS element was not found

Tags: php, automated-tests, phpstorm, codeception

I'm trying to write a test to a login page. There are only input field and submit button.

HTML/CSS on page:
[image: HTML/CSS on page]

My .yml file:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester modules:
enabled:
    - phpBrowser:
        url: https://myloginpage.test
    - \Helper\Acceptance
```

1.My test file:

```
<?php class SigninCest {
public function loginSuccessfully(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->amOnPage('https://myloginpage.test');
    $I->see('Enter e-mail');
    $I->fillField('userIdentifier','myemail@email.com');
    $I->click('button[type=submit]');
    $I->see('Successful login');
}}
```

In this case I am getting this error :  Fail  Form field by Label or CSS element with 'userIdentifier' was not found.

[image: Error message]

I am aware that

> `$I->fillField('userIdentifier','myemail@email.com');`

also can be written as

> $I->fillField("//input[@type='text']", "myemail@email.com");

or

> $I->fillField(['name' => 'userIdentifier'], 'myemail@email.com');

So after I make changes

2.My test file

```
<?php class SigninCest {
public function loginSuccessfully(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->amOnPage('https://myloginpage.test');
    $I->see('Enter e-mail');
    $I->fillField("//input[@type='text']", "myemail@email.com");
    $I->click('button[type=submit]');
    $I->see('Successful login');
}}
```

In this case I am getting the same error: Form field by Label or CSS element with '//input[@type='text']' was not found.

[image: Error message]

In third case

3.My test file:

```
 <?php class SigninCest {
public function loginSuccessfully(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->amOnPage('https://myloginpage.test');
    $I->see('Enter e-mail');
    $I->fillField(['name' => 'userIdentifier'], 'myemail@email.com');
    $I->click('button[type=submit]');
    $I->see('Successful login');
}}
```

Error message: Fail   element with name 'userIdentifier' was not found.

[image: Error message]

Please help me find what I am missing here.

Comment: Please make sure that your HTML is valid first. `<div class>` and `value` attribute without value doesn't look right.

Comment: HTML validator doesn't show any errors, value field originally contains autocomplete  data ( value = "myemail@email.com" ). I've found a similar task here https://stackoverflow.com/q/54865161/11118663 (with a different issue). You have recommended to use $I->fillField(['input' => '.form-control'], "myEmailAddress"); in my case this leads to  [PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] Array to string conversion

Answer (score 2):

the function `amOnPage` takes URLs relative to the settings in the yml configuration. To provide the complete URL, you should use the function `amOnUrl` function. So you might want to write the test in the following way

```
public function loginSuccessfully(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
   $I->amOnPage('/');
   $I->see('Enter e-mail');
   $I->fillField("//input[@type='text']", 'myemail@email.com');
   $I->click('button[type=submit]');
   $I->see('Successful login');
}
```